# cuComplex.h and exp()

Tags: c, cuda

Q0:

Is exp() supported by cuComplex.h?

Q1:

How to write A = B * exp(i * C), where A, B, C are same size arrays of real numbers? Is this right?

main:

```
cuComplex A;
float B;
cuComplex c;
```

kernel:

```
c[idx] = ( 0, C[idx] );

A[idx] = B[idx] * exp( c[idx] );
```

Q2:

cuComplex contains 2 float numbers which means I have to allocate 2 times more memory then for original matrix. is there any way to create pure imaginary number?

Comment: What does "is there any way to reate pure imaginary number?" mean?

Comment: There are so many things wrong here - try looking at cuComplex.h and use the functions there for complex arithmetic.

Comment: talonmies: sry, "create pure imaginary number" like: a = i * 4, where i imaginary unit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cuComplex.h only offers some basic operations on cuComplex (principally those used inside the CUBLAS and CUFFT libraries), the exponential function is not supported.

You can implement the exponential yourself using component-wise arithmetic. cuComplex stores the real part of a complex number in the x component and the imaginary part in the y component. Given a complex number z = x + i*y, the exponent can be computed as:

exp(z) = exp(x) * (cos(y) + i * sin(y))

This leads to the following CUDA code (untested):

```
cuComplex my_complex_exp (cuComplex arg)
{
   cuComplex res;
   float s, c;
   float e = expf(arg.x);
   sincosf(arg.y, &s, &c);
   res.x = c * e;
   res.y = s * e;
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't need `float e=expf(cuCrealf(arg))` since they're dealing with purely imaginary exponents. +1 for `sincosf`, it can indeed be quite a lot faster than a `sinf` and a `cosf` together; almost as fast as _each_ of them on my GT540M.

Answer (score 1):

Thrust also now has support for [complex exponentials](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__complex__numbers_gaa0244ebb87c7d942ff9b1d50c8845ff9.html#gaa0244ebb87c7d942ff9b1d50c8845ff9).

It's not necessary to otherwise be using thrust for this capability.  You can include the thrust complex header file, and use these constructs in ordinary CUDA code.

```
$ cat t1793.cu
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__host__ __device__
cuFloatComplex my_complex_exp (cuFloatComplex arg)
{
   cuFloatComplex res;
   float s, c;
   float e = expf(arg.x);
   sincosf(arg.y, &s, &c);
   res.x = c * e;
   res.y = s * e;
   return res;
}

__global__ void demo(){

  cuFloatComplex a = make_cuFloatComplex(1.0f, 1.0f);
  thrust::complex<float> b(1.0f, 1.0f);
  printf("thrust: %f,%f, cuComplex: %f,%f\n", exp(b).real(), exp(b).imag(), cuCrealf( my_complex_exp(a)), cuCimagf(my_complex_exp(a)));
}

int main(){

  demo<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t1793 t1793.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1793
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
thrust: 1.468694,2.287355, cuComplex: 1.468694,2.287355
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```